# How to add multiple rows from JTable to MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have been trying to add multiple rows from JTable to my MySQL Database, but only the first row is registered and not the rest.

Here's my code:

```
 DefaultTableModel tblmodel= (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
  
 
  if (tblmodel.getRowCount()==0)
  {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Table is Empty");
      }
  else {
            
      try
      {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

          Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root","123456");
          
      
      for (int i=0; i<tblmodel.getRowCount(); i++)
      {
          String pid = (String)jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0);
    String pname = (String)jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1);
    int price = (int)jTable1.getValueAt(i, 2);
    int qty = (int)jTable1.getValueAt(i, 3);
    int tprice = (int)jTable1.getValueAt(i, 4);
    
    String query = "Insert into invoice(product_id, product_name, price,quantity, total_price) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
 PreparedStatement ps;
    ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
   
    
    
     ps.setString(1, pid);
    ps.setString(2, pname);
    ps.setInt(3, price);
    ps.setInt(4, qty);
    ps.setInt(5, tprice);
          ps.execute();
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this , "Data added Successfully");
          tblmodel.setRowCount(0);
          
      }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          
          }
```

Comment: why are u setting the rowcount to zero?

Comment: @halfer Apologies. I'm new to stack and I'm not quite familiar with the rules. I'll ensure that this would not happen in he foreseeable future.

Comment: Thanks Joshua! The idea with Stack Overflow is that questions (and their answers) become almost like documentation, and so succinct technical writing is preferred - ideally tailored to broad/general cases as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code

```
tblmodel.setRowCount(0)
```

is causing it to break out of the loop after the first iteration.

Comment: I used it to reset the JTable after it was done saving.

Comment: reset a table means to clear it. is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, I removed tblmodel.setRowCount (0) and it worked perfectly fine, but I am now unable to clear the jTable as this function used to clear it.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly when you want to clear it but how about clearing it after you are out of the for loop?